# Creating a "settings" option

Tags: iphone, ios, settings, uiwindow

I want to have a settings toggle on my app's first screen.

On my main view (the first one that shows when the app loads) I have a table. Each cell loads a different view.

I want to have a toggle on my main view that will change a few aspects of how the other views appear (text color and background image to be specific).

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using NSUserDefaults. Here is the code that should be activated wherever the user changes their settings.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBOOL:YES forKey@"Whatever"];
```

And then, in the viewDidLoad part of the new screen, paste this:

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"Whatever"] == YES)

{

    //Then do your settings here, for example if whatever toggles the color

    //then type: view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor redColor];

}
```

Obviously there are better ways than to use a bool to store info with NSUserDefaults. I would actually read Apple's documentation for this one. It's interesting and makes sense.

Comment: That's EXACTLY what I have been looking for:-) thank you very much

Comment: I typed all that in where I need it, no errors, but it's not working. Any ideas???

Comment: Make sure the key (Whatever) matches up EXACTLY when using the if statement. Capitalization, spelling, etc. Also, in some cases, it is delayed in saving stuff to NSUserDefaults. It's not supposed to be delayed, but I would activate the code (did you place it in a button? tap the button), wait a sec, and then try it. Tell me if that works (the code here is definitely correct).

Comment: Oh I feel stupid, I put it in the viewDidLoad, instead of viewDidAppear. It works now. But I have a question. It doesn't  apply changes until like 1/2 a second after the view has fully appeared.

Comment: Huh, you're supposed to put it in viewDidLoad. I'm assuming viewDidAppear is after the view appears, which wouldn't work as well as viewDidLoad. Could you try looking up an NSUserDefaults sample code project and see if that works on your computer?

Comment: I fouls I have to put it twice. Once in viewDidLoad, and once in viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has some great docs for application preferences:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Preferences/Preferences.html

Here's a great library that simplifies some things for you also:

http://www.inappsettingskit.com/